# CompilerParameters class skype (Skype4COM) library error

Tags: c#, api, compiler-construction, skype, skype4com

I'm writting a program with Skype API (Skype4COM) and decided to make a runtime compilation. Everything worked perfectly before I decided to use in my compilation Skype API's library. When I tried to do it, program told me: "Metadata file 'c:\Users\Алексей\Dropbox\Skype Bot\Skype Bot\bin\Debug\Skype4COM.dll' could not be opened -- 'Attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format'". How I can fix it?
Here is code:

```
public delegate object Do();
    protected static string Compile(string str)
    {
        try
        {
            var csc = new CSharpCodeProvider(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "CompilerVersion", "v3.5" } });
            CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters(new[] { "mscorlib.dll", "System.Core.dll", "System.dll", "SKYPE4COM.dll" }) { GenerateInMemory = true };
            //parameters.LinkedResources.Add("Skype4COM.dll");
            //parameters.EmbeddedResources.Add("SKYPE4COMLib.dll");
            //parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("");

            CodeTypeReferenceExpression csSystemConsoleType = new CodeTypeReferenceExpression("System.Console");

            CompilerResults results = csc.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, str);

            if (results.Errors.Count >= 1) return results.Errors[0].ErrorText;

            Type t = results.CompiledAssembly.GetType("Program");
            MethodInfo m = t.GetMethod("Method");

            Do DoMethod;
            DoMethod = (Do)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Do), m);
            return DoMethod().ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return e.Message;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First be sure your dll has been [registered](http://donchevp.blogspot.it/2008/08/skype4com-lib-how-to-register-skype.html).

If you create a test project and you add a COM reference to `Skype4COM.dll` then Visual Studio will create an interop assembly `Interop.Skype4COM.dll`. You have to add a reference to that file (in the same way you added a reference to `System.Core.dll`, for example).

Comment: Thank you, but now it says: "Metadata file 'Interop.Skype4COM.dll' could not be found".

Comment: @NegiRussian You have to create it manually (I suggest you create a dummy VS project where you add that COM reference then simply copy the interop assembly).

Comment: I did so, I registered this library, created a new project and added it to the references :(

Comment: Now pick the interop assembly, move it to a known (accessible) directory and use it as a normal reference for the compiler (with path).

Comment: Oh I love you sooo much! Thank you!

Comment: Um, ok. It works when I write "Skype skype;" but when I write "Skype skype = new Skype();", it gives an error: Could not load file or assembly "Interop.SKYPE4COMLib, Version = 1.0.0.0, Culture = neutral , PublicKeyToken = null "or one of its dependencies. Can not find the file specified.

Comment: And yes, file path is C:\Games\Interop.SKYPE4COMLib.dll

Comment: Put that file in the same directory of your compiled application (I never tried, I guess it can be in the same directory of your application). If it doesn't work attach an handler to the AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx)